# Not-found page demands root-layout, meaning multiple root layouts not possible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

Rephrased my problem: The `not-found` page in my `app` dir requires a root-layout which I added to my `app` dir. But now I can no longer use multiple root layouts. Below structure simply does not work. How to fix?

The `not-found` page can only be put here `app/not-found.tsx` apparently. Anywhere else it does not render, meaning it does not work putting it in `app/(routes)/not-found.tsx`.

```
app
> _components
> (routes)
>> about
>>> page.tsx
>> layout.tsx (= root layout for my "about" page) <<< does not work!
> not-found.tsx
> layout.tsx (= root layout actually only created here for the "not-found" page)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts) answer your question?

Comment: @FabioNettis - The not-found page does not render when I put it in a not-found-folder with its own root layout

Comment: That makes sense. A not found page can be placed anywhere in your app and renders for all descendend routes.

Comment: @FabioNettis - sorry, I do not understand. I rephrased my question. I cannot have multiple root layouts when the "not-found" page forces me to create a root-layout in my app folder.

Comment: Just read the docs properly please

Comment: @FabioNettis - `not-found.tsx` can only be put in `app/not-found.tsx` for it to render and nowhere else. Putting it inside `app/(routes)/not-found.tsx` does not work.

Comment: That is **not true**. It will render for every route contained in `(routes)`. As I previously said it renders for all descendent routes. So as long as there is a layout file in `(routes)`, it will indeed work.

Comment: @FabioNettis - Well, I wish it worked but it does not. Tested it in a second project too. I find it also unbelievable but what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root `app/not-found.tsx` will handle both of these cases:

- if there's a `notFound` function thrown in a component
- if there's a URL mismatch (the URL accessed for the app doesn't exist)

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found

However, any nested `not-found.{js,tsx}` in any folders **will not handle URL mismatches**. They will only handle manually thrown `notFound` exceptions. So if you try to go to a page that doesn't exist, it will still show the global not-found page unless the page exists and you're manually calling the `notFound` method from nextjs.

Hope that helps and answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue while having multiple root layouts(multiple top level route groups). Putting `not-found.tsx` under both layout roots didn't help. And of course putting it under app folder like `app/not-found.tsx` because it requires root layout which is not possible due to multiple root layouts because of multiple top level route groups.

So my current workaround is to create a catch all route in the route group that makes sense like `[...not-found]/page.tsx` and in that page you simply call `notFound()` from `next/navigation`. Next you need to now add `not-found.tsx` file to that route group. Now visiting any route that is not defined will hit that catch all route page which will call `notFound()` function and nextjs will render the `not-found.tsx` that you have defined.

Below is my folder structure currently and it is working as expected for now:

[image]

**Note**

- As you can see above, I have two route groups, `auth` and `main` which each has a layout file. So it is important to know that the catch all route page will take the layout based on where you choose to put your file. In my case it takes the layout of the `main` route group.

There is still an active github discussion on this issue if you want to follow: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50034